# Hydraulic rim brake with racing bike levers

Tags: brake-levers, magura, hydraulic-rim-brake

I came across the picture below which claims to show racing bike levers of a Magura hydraulic rim brake ([source](https://radtouren-magazin.com/zubehoer/fahrrad-zubehoer/bremsen/die-legende-lebt-lange-leser-erfahrungen-mit-magura-hs.html)). According to the source website the displayed break levers belong to Magura HS77. I can find Magura HS77 on the internet but not with racing bike levers nor do I find any other racing bike levers for hydraulic rim brakes. Is anyone aware of the existence of racing bike levers for hydraulic rim brakes or hydraulic rim brakes with racing bike levers?

[image]

Comment: Are you interested in Magura specifically? If not, SRAM has hydraulic rim brake calipers, compatible with regular road bike hydraulic levers.

Comment: @Klaster_1 I think SRAM *did* have these under the Force 11s model, but because this is a niche market, I'm not sure if it's still in production. This guy has a bike with those calipers: https://cyclingtips.com/2019/12/bikes-of-the-bunch-stinner-aero-camino/

Comment: @WeiwenNg even if it's not in production, it's still quite available on eBay and online bike stores, unlike Magura from 20+ years ago.

Answer (score 2):

SRAM call this 'HRR'.

https://cyclingtips.com/2015/06/sram-red-22-hydraulic-groupset-review/

http://www.bicyclingaustralia.com.au/news/sram-s-700-10speed-hydro-road-rim-brake-hrr-fitment-and-bleeding

Old parts, but 22 speed is new enough. Check that if you buy they are not subject to a recall.

https://www.cpsc.gov/Recalls/2014/sram-recalls-hydraulic-bicycle-brakes